# How to update UI based on push notifcations when app is closed (React Native)

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, mobile, push-notification

Apologies for the somewhat general question - I'm not really sure what direction to take this in.

I'm working on a chat feature in a mobile app (React Native is that is relevant), and handling push notifications with OneSignal. I'm currently updating the chat interface with an indicator for unread messages, which is updated when a new push notification comes in for a chat. However, this functionality doesn't run when the app is closed.

Anyone have experience with a similar functionality, or have any guidance on how to handle this feature? I'm at kind of a loss on how to proceed.

Comment: Don't know about OneSignal, but react-native-fcm provides a method `FCM.getInitialNotification` when app is started by pressing the notification and you can get the notification data using this on app start. May be OneSignal provides something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can know that application is opened via manually(by pressing app icon) or via notification. Depending on the opening of application and parameters from push notification you can change the UI.

PS : If your application is chat app, isn't real time (like firebase realtime database)? I think you don't even need push notification to update UI if it is realtime?